# Convert column in Kendo Grid from int to string

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is probably an easy answer but even after searching through documentation i haven't figured it out yet.   I have a column in a Kendo Grid that i would like to convert from an integer to a string for filtering purposes.  Basically on my ID column,  if the user types in 3 it will filter the records for 3, 13, 23 33, ect.  Right now what it does in the filter after i type in 3 and hit enter, it converts it to 33.00       Below is the Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RequestViewModel>
      ()
      .Name("MyGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Title("Ticket No.")
              .ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("#=ID#", "View", new { ID = "#=ID#" }).ToHtmlString())
              .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
         //  Something here like   .ToString()

          columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedDate).Title("Submitted On").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(CreatedDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH.mm.ss') #").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Template("DateTimeFilter")));
          columns.Bound(c => c.DepartmentName).Title("Department Requested To").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
          columns.Bound(c => c.Technician).Title("Technician Assigned").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")));
      })
      .Sortable()
      .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
      .Pageable(pageable => pageable
          .Refresh(true)
          .PageSizes(true)
          .ButtonCount(5))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .ServerOperation(true)
          .PageSize(10)
          .Model(model => model.Id(x => x.ID))
          .Read(read => read.Action("Action", "DataSource"))
       )
```

Comment: You could add another field to your `RequestViewModel` called "StringID". Then in your `read.Action("Action", "DataSource")` method, populate that field with the string value of your ID field. Then set the "StringID" field as a column in your grid.

Comment: Yes Supersnake that worked just fine,  but thought there would be a way to convert it to a string on the client in the Kendo Grid itself.  But it did fix my problem.